# How do I disable images on my firefox 31.0

Tags: windows-7

I don't seem to know where to disable the image. I don't want to see any image when I open my Yahoo mail or any other mail. I have tried so many things, I have even looked for the option in the "Option" bar but is not there. Please help me. I am desperate to disable it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go to about:config, search for this option "permissions.default.image" change to 2.

Possible values:

1 -- Allow all images to load, regardless of origin. (Default)

2 -- Block all images from loading.

3 -- Prevent third-party images from loading.

OR

Download the [Adblock plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/firefox) plugin, make a new filter for the domain you want in this case yahoo, disable all images for that domain.

Answer (score -1):

Use an appropriate addon for FireFox. For example:
[Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/) or [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/).